# Active Directory Password Change - Won't search down contexts

Tags: asp-classic, vb6

I have a legacy script that handles some password resets for our students accounts but it seems to hit a bit of a snag when users are moved to Sub OU's and causes issues.

Basically the following is the LDAP connection string.

```
strLDAP ="LDAP://Studc01.student.college.ad:389/OU=Students,DC=student,DC=college,DC=ad"
```

If student accounts reside in this main OU, the script seems to be able to reset their password to the default specified. However if accounts are in sub OU's from the top Students OU, the script falls over and fails out.

The script is as follows and takes some info from previously input text fields.

```
if request.form("AccountName")<> "" then
sAMAccountName = request.form("AccountName")
cUser = request.form("User")
else
response.write("There was an error no account details were given.")
response.end
End if

strLDAP ="LDAP://Studc01.student.college.ad:389/OU=Students,DC=student,DC=college,DC=ad"

Set obj = GetObject(strLDAP)

for each objUser in obj
if ucase(objUser.sAMAccountName) = ucase(sAMAccountName) then
Exit for
end if
next

Response.write("The password has now been reset (Password1) for account " &   objUser.sAMAccountName & ", thank you")

objUser.SetPassword "Password1"
objUser.Put "pwdLastSet", 0
objUser.SetInfo
```

The scripts seem to use the network service in application pool within IIS to run - any ideas on why it is unable to search down contexts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping users with `For Each` is extremely inefficient. Try `ADsDSOObject` OLEDB provider with ADO for querying AD subtree like this

```
strLDAP = "LDAP://" & GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE").Get("defaultNamingContext")
sAMAccountName = "wqw"

With CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    .Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;Page Size=1000;Searchscope=2"
    With .Execute("<" & strLDAP & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & sAMAccountName & "));ADsPath;subtree")
        If Not .EOF Then
            Set objUser = GetObject(.Fields("ADsPath").Value)
            WScript.echo "Will reset password of " & objUser.name
        End If
    End With
End With
```

Also note that you have to filter domain users with `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))` otherwise risk on resetting passwords for computer accounts.

Comment: The domain that staff are changing passwords from is different to the domain that the students are on. Are there any considerations that need to be made to reflect that?

Comment: No, just use your `strLDAP` and this snippet should acquire `objUser` as in original.